Create metadata Container with sfdx command
Is it possible to create a Metadata Container using sfdx command ?
then to create an apex class and deploy the metadataContainer to my Salesforce Org
I want to update an apex class that i have in my Salesforce Org using a metadata Container. I did this with Postman Tooling APi. Iam asking if I can do the same thing using sfdx commands on vs code terminal ?
I tried this command sfdx force:mdapi:container:create -d ./metadata
I get this :  »   Warning: force mdapi container create is not a sf command.
Did you mean force mdapi convert? (Y/n)
»   Error: Run sf help force for a list of available commands.

What do you mean by "container"? Something like a qemu/docker container, or something else? If you are looking for something like a docker container, the closest thing Salesforce proper (i.e. excluding acquisitions like Heroku) has would be a "scratch org".

It's still not clear what you're asking for. My best guess is that you're either asking about scratch orgs, or second-generation packaging (i.e. 2GP). The more details you can include, the better.

Again, you need to really go into extreme detail, especially when you're using nonstandard terminology. Mentioning the Tooling API does help a bit, but there's still not nearly enough information for 99% of people to understand what you're talking about/trying to do. The best I can come up with so far is ignore the concept of a "metadata container", that's not a thing with the Salesforce CLI. The CLI abstracts that concept away from us normal devs. Just use sf project deploy start -o <your org username or alias> -m ApexClass:<your class name here> to deploy changes to an Apex Class

@DerekF MetadataContainer is a Tooling API concept, primarily to support the Developer Console. I guess they're hoping to integrate the Salesforce CLI with an IDE?

The MetadataContainer is part of the Tooling API, not the Metadata API. As such, there is no corresponding mdapi command. The mdapi command deals with commands in the Metadata Developer Guide. The only Tooling API functions in the CLI are those related to running Unit Tests and Execute Anonymous scripts. To deploy code to an org, use project deploy start.
